# How to prevent background color of changing the color of txt

Tags: css

i have a h6 inside a div

```
   <div class="cylinder" data-v-5147e140="">
    <div  data-v-5147e140="">
      <h6 class="quantite" data-v-5147e140="">27.61 T</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="water" data-v-5147e140=""></div>
  </div>
```

the code above give this :

[image: Result]

but the text on the div on the left is not clear , how can i make it like the text on the right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="cylinder" data-v-5147e140="">
  <div class="quantite-parent" data-v-5147e140="">
    <h6 class="quantite" data-v-5147e140="">27.61 T</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="water" data-v-5147e140=""></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.quantite-parent {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

Main container needs to create a new [MDN: the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) to enable child elements to be positioned 'absolute' inside.

Once that has been done, the text content elements (`.content` in the snippet) can be positioned on top of the `.water` by settings its `z-index` higher than 0 (= html default).

I'm using [MDN: inset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset) to stretch the child elements to fill the parent `.cylinder`.

Check the commented **snippet** below:

```css
.cylinder {
    position: relative; /* new stacking context */
    /* Will force 'absolute' child elements to be
       positioned inside this element */

    /* eye-candy */
    height: 200px; width: 100px; background-color: Gainsboro;
}

.content {
    inset: 0;           /* stretch to fill parent */

    position: absolute; /* position within parent */
    z-index: 1;         /* placed above .water */

    /* Use CSS Grid to Vert/Hor center text */
    display: grid; place-items: center;
}

.water {
    inset: 40% 0 0 0; /* percent from top, fill from bottom */
    /* modify the '40%' to your requirements. Any legal unit will do */

    position: absolute; /* position within parent */
    /* z-index will be default 0 */

    /* eye-candy */
    background-color: Orange; opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<div class="cylinder" data-v-5147e140="">
    <div class="content" data-v-5147e140="">
        <h6 class="quantite" data-v-5147e140="">27.61 T</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="water" data-v-5147e140=""></div>
</div>
```